# Spring Boot - Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12]

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web project, 
I'm trying to set up SSL with a certificate provided by my employer.

The PFX file is currently working fine to achieve SSL on stand-alone Tomcat with the following config:

```
    <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" enableLookups="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" keystoreFile="server.pfx" 
        keystoreType="PKCS12"  keystorePass="secret"
        acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
        clientAuth="false"
        sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

In Spring Boot, with the embedded Tomcat I use the following `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8088
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-password=secret
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=1
```

when I start the project, I get the error message

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12] with path [file:/Users/user/workspace/tracking/target/classes/server.pfx] due to [PKCS12 not found]

the command `keytool -list -keystore /Users/user/workspace/tracking/target/classes/server.pfx'`

returns

> Keystore type: JKS
>
> Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> 1, 15-Mar-2018, PrivateKeyEntry, 
>   Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F8:A0:CF:A6:AF:B4:ED:53:A0:79:25:03:04:D9:79:F0:FC:B2:49:DF

is there a different value I should be using for `server.ssl.key-store-type`?

**UPDATE**

I also tried changing to `server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS` but then I get:

> IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by 
>   certificate chain

Is there a way around either of these problems?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same server.pfx file? keystoreType = "PKCS12" should return an error if the type is JKS. It looks like the file Spring Boot is loading is a copy that only imported the private key but not the CA certificates.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but it's definitely a copy of the same file

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?

Comment: A private key has to be either self signed, or accompanied by a certificate change, which you get, if a Certificate Authority is signing your Certificate Signing Request. This you can import (with the same alias as your private key) into your keystore, and then have the full monty.
The self-signed certificate is created by java's keytool, if you say -genkeypair

Comment: same issue.. still struggling to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for the party, but I faced a similar issue.
I tried to add Bouncy Castle's keystore to my Spring's app:
`server.ssl.key-store-type=BCFKS` and my app always switched back to `PKCS12` for some reason.

I fixed it by changing properties name:

instead of `server.ssl.key-store-type=BCFKS`

I added `server.ssl.keyStoreType=BCFKS`